# Error in for loop using a function within a function

Tags: function, python-3.6

I am defining a function to create a polynomial from data, defining another function to use this polynomial in an equation and then using a for loop for it to run until the value that is being calculated is equal or less than 0.
When running the for loop, it gives the following error for when the loop is supposed to end - ' The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() '

```
def poly(Hi):
return np.poly1d(np.polyfit(xs, ys, deg=5))

def hip1(Hi,g,e,d,dt):
return Hi -((np.pi*d**2)*np.sqrt(2*g*(Hi + e))*dt) / (4*poly(Hi))

H = [6]
t = [0]
dt = 1
d = 0.25
e = 1
g = 9.81

for i in range(1000000):
t.append((i+1)*dt)
H.append(hip1(H[i],g,e,d,dt))
if H[i+1] < 0: break

------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-11-a17bdee03e19> in <module>
  2     t.append((i+1)*dt)
  3     H.append(hip1(H[i],g,e,d,dt))
----> 4     if H[i+1] < 0: break

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is 
ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried to run your code to understand the problem.

I ran this code:

```
for i in range(1000000):
    t.append((i+1)*dt)
    H.append(hip1(H[i],g,e,d,dt))
    print(H)
    print(i)
    if H[i+1] < 0:
        break
```

I've tested to print `H` and `i`. So, the loop crash at the first iteration
and print:

`H = [6, array([2.54840628, 2.54840628, 2.54840628, 2.54840628, 2.54840628, 2.54840628])]`

Hence, you can't access to the H[i+1] value seeing that it's an array.
Your function `hip1` return another array and not a single value.

EDIT:

New version of your code:

```
H = [6]
t = [0]
dt = 1
d = 0.25
e = 1
g = 9.81
xs = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
ys = [11700, 9700, 6700, 4500, 3200, 1800, 0]


for i in range(10000):
    t.append((i+1)*dt)
    H.append(np.mean(hip1(H[i],g,e,d,dt)))
    if H[i+1] < 0:
        break

print(H)
```

For the last problem, I've just used the mean of the array return by hip1.
It seems that the value of the array was closed, so it was a solution to have a single value. Maybe it's wrong in your context, but the idea is to have an only value and not an array.

Now, you can easily run your program and test your values.

Comment: It works when I only have the hip1 function, if I input the polynomial directly into it and not as a function. How would I have to edit the for loop to break when reaching 0?

Comment: There is data for the polynomial function - xs = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
ys = [11700, 9700, 6700, 4500, 3200, 1800, 0]. I forgot to show this above the function.

Comment: I found out that the issue is with the function poly(Hi). This function is just staying as the polynomial and isn't taking any variable values. Do you know how I assign a value to the polynomial?

Comment: You want that your function poly(Hi) takes more than one parameter ?
Do you have an example of what you want ?